# Filtering an array of Data Models

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, data-structures, enums

I have a data model which includes an array of structs. I'm using this to populate a tableView. Works great, but I need help filtering the data.

I want to be able to filter by the extremeSport enum (via pressing a button in the UI.) In my example below, there are 3 sports with 8 tricks. Ultimately, there will be about 10 sports and 150-200 tricks (potentially many more tricks.) Filtering makes sense here.

The problem is I don't know how to go from Sections to ExtremeModel, so that I can filter by extremeSport. The closest I got was sorting by sectionName letter.

```
struct ExtremeModel {
    let trick: String
    let definition: String
    let extremeSport: Sport
    enum Sport {
        case bmx
        case skateboarding
        case snowboarding
    }
}
struct Sections {
    let sectionName: String
    let Objects: [ExtremeModel]
}

struct Data {
    static func allTricks() -> [Sections] {
        return [
            Sections(sectionName: "A", Objects: [
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Axel Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding)
            ]),
            Sections(sectionName: "B", Objects: [
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Back Flip", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Bar Spin", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .bmx),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Bunny Hop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .bmx)
            ]),
            Sections(sectionName: "S", Objects: [
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Shifty", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Shuvit", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Stalefish", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding)
            ]),
        ]
    }
}
```

Usage. This is where I am having trouble doing the sort.

```
let allTerms = Data.allTricks()

// Here, I am filtering by Section Name. I want to filter by extremeSport, so I can update the view based on sports.
let filteredSports = allTerms.filter { (sport:Sections) -> Bool in
    return sport.sectionName == "A"
}
```

**How do I filter the allTricks() data by extremeSport enum?**

Comment: I would use a different struct name than `Data`, since there is a Foundation class called `Data`

Comment: Great call! I've renamed this to SportData :)

Comment: All  those `var`s and implicitly unwrapped optionals... yikes!

Comment: @Alexander - thank you for pointing that out! I've been doing it wrong this whole time. eeeek! I've edited my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rework your model a bit. I would suggest you use a `Dictionary`, instead of an `Array`, so that you can more naturally find sets of tricks you're interested in.

```
enum ExtremeSport {
    case bmx
    case skateboarding
    case snowboarding
}

struct ExtremeSportTrick {
    let name: String
    let definition: String
    let extremeSport: ExtremeSport
}


struct SportData {
    static let allTricks = [
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Axel Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Back Flip", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bar Spin", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .bmx),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bunny Hop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .bmx),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Shifty", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Shuvit", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
        ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Stalefish", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding)
    ]

    static func allTricksByFirstLetter() -> [String: [ExtremeSportTrick]] {
        return Dictionary(grouping: allTricks, by: { String($0.name.first!) })
    }

    static func allTricksBySport() -> [ExtremeSport: [ExtremeSportTrick]] {
        return Dictionary(grouping: allTricks, by: { $0.extremeSport })
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func prettyString<T>() -> String where Dictionary.Value == [T] {
        return Array(self)
            .map{ key, values in """
            \(key): [
                \(values.map{ "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ",\n\t"))
            ]
            """ }
            .joined(separator: ",\n")
    }
}

let allTricksBySport = SportData.allTricksBySport()
let allTricksByFirstLetter = SportData.allTricksByFirstLetter()
let allBMXTricks = allTricksBySport[.bmx]
let allATricks = SportData.allTricksByFirstLetter()["A"]

print("=== All tricks by sport:")
print(allTricksBySport.prettyString())
print("\n\n\n=== All tricks by first letter:")
print(allTricksByFirstLetter.prettyString())
print("\n\n\n=== All bmx tricks:")
print(allBMXTricks!.map{ "\($0)"}.joined(separator: ",\n"))
print("\n\n\n=== All tricks whose name starts with \"A\":")
print(allATricks!.map{ "\($0)"}.joined(separator: ",\n"))
```

Result:

```
=== All tricks by sport:
snowboarding: [
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Back Flip", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.snowboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Shifty", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.snowboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Stalefish", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.snowboarding)
],
bmx: [
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bar Spin", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.bmx),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bunny Hop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.bmx)
],
skateboarding: [
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Axel Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Shuvit", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding)
]



=== All tricks by first letter:
B: [
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Back Flip", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.snowboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bar Spin", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.bmx),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bunny Hop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.bmx)
],
A: [
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Axel Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding)
],
S: [
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Shifty", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.snowboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Shuvit", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding),
    ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Stalefish", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.snowboarding)
]



=== All bmx tricks:
ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bar Spin", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.bmx),
ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Bunny Hop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.bmx)



=== All tricks whose name starts with "A":
ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding),
ExtremeSportTrick(name: "Axel Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: Untitled.ExtremeSport.skateboarding)
```

Depending on your needs for mutability, how large/expensive these arrays are, etc., you may want to use a `lazy var` to implement `allTricksByFirstLetter` and `allTricksBySport`.

Comment: in the allTricksBySport function, I am getting: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Dictionary<String, [ExtremeSportTrick]>' to return type '[ExtremeSport : [ExtremeSportTrick]]'

Comment: @Joe Oops, I had made a copy/paste mistake. See my edit

Comment: This is awesome! You went above and beyond by simplifying my data, and providing multiple ways to sort. Thank you!

Comment: @Joe :) `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` is pretty great

Comment: just one more quick question! You've now given me the idea to sort sports by seasons :) I tried this: let allSummerSports = allTricksBySport[.skateboarding, .bmx] - however it's giving me 'Missing argument label 'default:' in subscript'

Comment: @Joe You can't subscript a dictionary by two things like that. The error is state that the closest thing it could, is [`Dictionary.subscript(key:default:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to sort all sports by season. As an example, I want to display all skateboarding and bmx sports (which excludes snowboarding). This is out of scope from my original question, and merely something out of curiosity on my end :) (so i understand if you want to skip over it!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163352/discussion-between-alexander-and-joe).

Answer (score 1):

A couple points up front:

- As @Alexander mentioned, you should think about the best way to structure your data. My answer involves the smallest amount of change to your code... think about whether this is appropriate.
- Struct names are singular by convention.

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
struct ExtremeModel {
    var trick: String!
    var definition: String!
    var extremeSport: Sport!
    enum Sport {
        case bmx
        case skateboarding
        case snowboarding
    }
}

// Struct names should be singular!
struct Section {
    var sectionName: String!
    var Objects: [ExtremeModel]!
}

// Renamed to avoid collision with Foundation's Data class
struct MyData {
    static func allTricks() -> [Section] {
        return [
            Section(sectionName: "A", Objects: [
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Acid Drop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Axel Stall", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding)
                ]),
            Section(sectionName: "B", Objects: [
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Back Flip", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Bar Spin", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .bmx),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Bunny Hop", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .bmx)
                ]),
            Section(sectionName: "S", Objects: [
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Shifty", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Shuvit", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .skateboarding),
                ExtremeModel(trick: "Stalefish", definition: "Lorem ipsum", extremeSport: .snowboarding)
                ]),
        ]
    }
}

let allTricks = MyData.allTricks()

let filteredSports = allTricks.filter { (section) -> Bool in
    return section.Objects.contains(where: { (extremeModel) -> Bool in
        return extremeModel.extremeSport == .skateboarding
    })
}

print(filteredSports.count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and for providing me with some helpful 'best-practice' tips. These will come in handy! :)

Comment: @joe no problem!

Comment: I have two projects set up, one with your help, and the other with alexanders help. regarding your solution - the filtering seems to be filtering the sections that contain the extreme sport (not section AND term). So for instance - if i filter .bmx - i will get all terms from section B (because section B is the only section that has bmx). Is there a way to filter both sections *and* terms to only display the sports?

Comment: Do you want an array that contains `Section`s or `ExtremeModel`s?

Comment: Both ExtremeModel organized by Section. I just want the filtering to remove all results that don't fit. For example - If I filter .bmx, I will have just section B with bar spin & bunny hop. Another example - if i filter .skateboarding, I will have section A (both tricks) and section S with Shuvit.

Comment: No, you can't do this without creating an entirely new `Section` struct. The 'Objects' within your struct are immutable so you can't remove items. I think you need to structure your data differently. In fact, do you really even need a `Section` that sorts your data by it's first letter? I'm not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163362/discussion-between-joe-and-toddg).